# Why does my image have right margin whitespace in flexbox?

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I make a banner and using flexbox (for first time), but pictures has this big white space after them (I need 6 pics in a row). I want this banner to be 100% width and pics must glue to borders, but last pic always have that white space after it. Maybe I can turn it off?

```css
.header-small-cars {
 list-style-type: none; 
 margin-top:30px;
 padding: 0; 
 width:100%;
 display: flex;
}

.header-small-cars__item {
 flex-grow: 1;
}

.header-car:link {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.header-car__name {
 font-size: 14px; 
 line-height: 20px; 
 color: #000; 
 font-weight: 400; 
 margin: 0 0 -3px 0;
}

.header-car__name span {
 color: #e17838; 
 font-size: 12px; 
 line-height: 20px;
}

.header-car__img { 
 height: 51px;
}

.header-car__img img{
 width: auto; 
 height: 51px;
}


.header-car__price {
 color: #e10025; 
 font-size: 12px; 
 line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header-small-cars">
                    <li class="header-small-cars__item">
                        <a href="#" class="header-car">
                            <h3 class="header-car__name">Lala <span class="header-car__name--sale">manu</span></h3>
                            <div class="header-car__img"><img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/690753888/HP_FG_006_Fixed_Gear_Bikes_Fixie.summ.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <span class="header-car__price">1999s.</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header-small-cars__item">
                        <a href="#" class="header-car">
                            <h3 class="header-car__name">Coco <span>Mala</span></h3>
                            <div class="header-car__img"><img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/690753888/HP_FG_006_Fixed_Gear_Bikes_Fixie.summ.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <span class="header-car__price">192882n.</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/snbrae5z/1/

Comment: yes, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two flex items in the flex container.

You've applied `flex-grow: 1` to both items:

```
.header-small-cars__item {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This means that all available width in the container is distributed evenly among both flex items.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/snbrae5z/3/

Once you add all six items, the space will be distributed evenly among all of them (with no changes to the CSS):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/snbrae5z/4/

With only two flex items, you can remove `flex-grow: 1` and add `justify-content: space-between` to the flex container. `space-between` aligns first and last items to the container edges:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/snbrae5z/1/